# Как использовать массив в случае выдачи рандомных чисел с ограничениями для объектов Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Проект - простенькая азартная игра "Мины". В проекте есть 25 2d объектов (плиток), каждому из которых надо выдать значение (0, либо 1), чтобы в зависимости от этого значения использовать объект (проигрыш, либо выигрыш). Также, важное условие, что значений 0 должно быть определенное количество (от 2 до 24), которое выбирается пользователем.
Предполагаю, что здесь нужно использовать массив, но не знаю, как ограничить выдачу нулей, если использовать метод рандома.

Answer (score 3):

Да всё просто.

1. Вначале генерируется рандомное число. Допустим это 10.
2. Далее заполняется массив от 0 до 24 (т.е. 25 элементов), где первые 10 (точнее сколько в рандоме указано) - это будут нули, остальные - 1
3. Перемешиваем массив.
4. PROFIT.